# babun won't run python3 on win10

Tags: windows-10, python, cygwin

I am building a new Win10 machine.  I have babun installed, and im trying to get python3 running.  Problem is it won't execute.

```
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.8
$ python3 --version
$
```

any ideas what would cause this?  or how to debug it?

output of debugging.  It looks like everything is noise, but im not sure.

```
[506] user@nsa_surveillance_01433:~ $ strace /usr/bin/python3 --version
strace.exe: error creating process C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\python3, (error 5)
[507] user@nsa_surveillance_01433:~ $ cygcheck python3
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-eventing-provider-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-3.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-2.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-2-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-2.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-enclave-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-2.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-delayload-l1-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-io-l1-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-job-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-threadpool-legacy-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-threadpool-private-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-2.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l2-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-2-2.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-2-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-2.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-3.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-localization-private-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-processsnapshot-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-2-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-3.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-security-base-l1-2-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-comm-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-realtime-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-processtopology-l1-2-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-namespace-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-2.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-xstate-l2-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-localization-l2-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-normalization-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-fibers-l2-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-sidebyside-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-appcompat-l1-1-1.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-coreFound: C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\python3
Found: C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\python3
 -> C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\python3.6m.exe
C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\python3.6m.exe
  C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\libpython3.6m.dll
    C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\cygwin1.dll
      C:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
        C:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll
        C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
    C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\cygintl-8.dll
      C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\cygiconv-2.dll
    C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\bin\cyggcc_s-1.dll
-windowserrorreporting-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-console-l2-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-psapi-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-core-psapi-ansi-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-security-appcontainer-l1-1-0.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find api-ms-win-eventing-provider-l1-1-0.dll
```

Comment: `cygcheck python3` and/or `strace /usr/bin/python3 --version` . Likely you are missing a library or an upgrade was incorrect.

Comment: i updated the question with the output.  i did a rebase to no avail.

Comment: error 5 =  Access is denied.